# Python: How can I make a new line when printing?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using Cmd, PIL, and Image to make a program called Visual Object Creator, aka VOC. I made a command prompt and when you type in a command, let's say, bluesquare, it creates just that. But when I do, it makes the image right in front of my command prompt. It looks terribly ugly. It makes me type the command in the next line, away from the (Cmd) prompt. It's hard to explain, just use trinket.io and see my problem, because that's the only compiler I find that works

I tried using /n and printing simply a blank line, but it never worked. I have seen the /n being used but it simply prints the actual /n and not the blank line. I am sorry I pasted the whole file, but every image creating command that I programmed does it!

```
from PIL import Image
from cmd import Cmd
class Root(Cmd):
  intro = "Visual Object Creator v.04."
  prompt = ">"
  def do_redsquare(self, inp):
    print("VOC created this image for you! rsqr.jpg")
    rs = Image.new("RGB", (50, 50), color = "red")
    rs.save("rsqr.jpg")
  def help_redsquare(self):
    print("VOC creates a red square under the filename rsqr.jpg.")
  def do_exit(self, inp):
    return True
  def help_exit(self):
    print("Ends the VOC application.")
  def do_greensquare(self, inp):
    print("VOC created this image for you! gsqr.jpg")
    gs = Image.new("RGB", (50, 50), color = "green")
    gs.save("gsqr.jpg")
  def help_greensquare(self):
    print("VOC creates a green sqare under the filename gsqr.jpg.")
  def do_bluesquare(self, inp):
    print("VOC created this image for you! bsqr.jpg")
    bs = Image.new("RGB", (50, 50), color = "blue")
    bs.save("bsqr.jpg")
  def help_bluesquare(self):
    print("VOC creates a blue square under the filename bsqr.jpg")
Root().cmdloop()
```

There were no errors, but it was making me enter commands on a blank line when I actually want to do it on the line of the (cmd) prompt.

Comment: you need `\n` instead of `/n`

Comment: Could you add a picture of your broken output, because for me it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The correct newline character for python is `\n`.

The `\` (backslash) is used to start an "escape sequence" which has special
meaning to Python. Some of the options are:

`\n` newline

`\t` tab

`\\` backslash

Comment: I guess I got it wrong because I barely ever use backslash i use /. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

print() should print a blank line. Example:

```
print('line 1')
print()
print('line 2')
```

will output:

```
line 1

line 2
```